# Regular expression to return part of a string, from within a file, in bash script

Tags: regex, bash

Ok I'm stumped!

I have a bash script.  First thing I do is run a command that outputs to a log file.  The result looks like this:

```
LINE1: ProgOut: Starting my thing <parm1> in this <parm2> ... 2014-01-22 

LINE2: 10:21:52.750 NOTIFICATION XYZ-000: My thing "<parm1>", inst "123456", sub 1 has started
```

`<parm1> and <parm2>` are input parameters and could therefore change.  All other text (except LINE1, LINE2 which are there for readability) are all standard output.

I need to read through and assign the value 123456 to a variable.

I have tried with a regular expression:

```
INST_ID=$(tail -5 "$LOG_FILE" | grep -oP "^ *My thing *\ *"<parm1>", inst \"\K[^\"]+")
```

but it obviously doesn't work and I'm struggling to find an alternative.  I had also thought fgrep / grep -f would be better, so I could read line by line?

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to get the value of inst (i.e. 123456, in this case) then use it for something else.

Comment: Then why is your code searching for `My thing`?

Comment: It's probably wrong.  How would you do it?

Comment: Are any of the answers below not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only these 2 lines in the log file so the word "inst" comes only before "123456" then cnicutar's answer should work. What do you get when you run

var=``cat <log_file_path> | grep inst | sed 's/.*inst "\(.*\)".*/\1/'``

echo $var

Answer (score 0):

Think this `grep` would help.

```
grep -o "inst \"[0-9]*\"" | grep -o [0-9]*
```

Comment: Sakthi, helping by not quite there as it doesn't return anything.  The first grep returns inst "123456" as you'd expect.  The second doesn't return.  If I take the * off, then I get 1,2,3,4,5,6 printed on seperate lines?

Comment: Actually i tested it in my machine. The second grep also returned the value.

#inst_id=`tail -n 1 test | grep -o "inst \"[0-9]*\"" | grep -o [0-9]*`

# echo $inst_id

123456

Comment: Thanks for testing for me.  I've noticed that if I do [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] - I get the return. But the number could be any length - hence you've used *.  There must be something I'm missing, but don't get what.